# how to use logical operators between two columns of different tables in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How do I use logical operators between two columns of different tables in CI?

I have to check a condition like:

```
$this->db->select('tbl.id ')
    ->from('tbl')
    ->join('table','tbl.company_id = table.company_id')
    ->where('tbl.maxprice >=table.maxprice')
    ->where('tbl.minprice <= table.minprice')
    ->order_by('tbl.date')
    ->get()
    ->row_array();
```

It shows an error: `unknown column table.maxprice`.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You must have to use alias.

Answer (score 0):

If your table name is really *table* then you should not use because some keywords are reserved vendor specific and table is a reserved keyword ,for now you can rewrite your query as below

```
$this->db->select('t.id ')
    ->from('tbl t')
    ->join('table t1', 't.company_id = t1.company_id') /* best is to change your table name from table to something else */
    ->where('t.maxprice >= t1.maxprice')
    ->where('t.minprice <= t1.minprice')
    ->order_by('t.date')
    ->get()
    ->row_array();
```

Comment: Actually I'm using it with pyrocms and I have a query like   $fpending = $this->db->select('temp_skshare.id')        ->from('temp_skshare')        ->where('temp_skshare.company_id', $compid)        ->join('companyshare','companyshare.company_id = temp_skshare.company_id')        ->where('temp_skshare.maxprice >= companyshare.maxprice')        ->where('temp_skshare.minprice <= companyshare.minprice')         ->order_by('temp_skshare.date')        ->get()        ->row_array();  and it should automatically add default_ in front of each table but not added only in case of companyshare.maxprice

Comment: @user3094124 use alias `->from('temp_skshare t')` , `->join('companyshare c','c.company_id = t.company_id')` donot use complete table names in join and in where() function as well

Answer (score 0):

like that

```
$this->db->select('tb.id ')
 ->from('tbl tb')
 ->join('table','tb.company_id = table.company_id')
 ->where('tb.maxprice >=table.maxprice')
 ->where('tb.minprice <= table.minprice')
 ->order_by('tbl.date')
 ->get()
 ->row_array();
```